# FFMPEG: same audio stream required in 2 output files

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to take an input AVI file with one video stream and one PCM audio stream and produce two AVC output files, with different scalings (1024:768 and 640:480), but with the same AAC audio stream in each of them.  How do I map this so both output files will contain an AAC stream as well as their respective video resized steam?  As I've got it doing now, the 2nd file has no audio.

Dan.

Comment: And what is it that you're currently using?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`-map` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) will allow you to choose which streams to output:

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1024:768[768];[0:v]scale=640:480[480]" \
-map "[768]" -map 1:a -shortest output_768.mp4 \
-map "[480]" -map 1:a -shortest output_480.mp4
```

If you wanted to get fancy you could use the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1) with the `select` option to only encode the audio once and use it for both outputs.